# I am a bit confused about when to use to be verbs before prepositions

Tags: prepositions

1. The book is ON the table: this sentence has a *to be* verb before the preposition "on"
2. Kayak ACROSS rivers and lakes: no *to be* verbs

Why not say kayak is across rivers?

3. he is behind me or he behind me?

Comment: _Kayak_ appears to be a verb in (2).

Comment: I assume "tobe verb" is a mistake, and you meant *to be* verb.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need the verb *to be* when saying that someone or something *is* in a particular place.

(2) doesn't make sense if 'kayak' is understood as a noun. You don't say where you found these sentences, but I would interpret it as

> [Paddle a] kayak across rivers and lakes.

Answer (score 1):

There is no *to be" verb in the second sentence, because "kayak" is a **verb**.

Normally "kayak" is a noun.  Here it is being used as a verb with the meaning "use a kayak".

You can say  "He kayaked across the river."  There is no "to be" verb, because there is verb "kayaked".  You can interpret your sentence as an imperative:

> {You must} Kayak across rivers and lakes.

Your first sentence is a copular sentence which gives the location of a the book. In English, copular sentence use a form of "be".

And so in the copular sentence "He is behind me", the verb "is" is required.  But you could write:

> He plays the piano behind me.

English sentences need a verb so "He behind me" is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

A sentence must contain a verb.

1. The book **is** ON the table. **Is** is the verb.
2. **Kayak** ACROSS rivers and lakes. **Kayak**- verb

kayak (noun)= a light narrow canoe

kayak (verb)= travel in or use a kayak.

They **kayaked** across the river.

3. 'He behind me' makes no sense. There is no verb.

He **is** behind me. He **stood** behind me. He **shut** the door behind me.